# Storing a cURL as a variable in Python

Tags: python, curl, module

So, my idea at the first point, was to execute a cURL after a given condition in Python.
I tryed to use the os module, using:

```
os.system(curl -k "http://myhost.com" -d'{"event": { "Error": "Error Found", "Host": "myhostname"}}')
```

But I had a syntax error.

I know it is hardcoded, and also that there is a module called requests in Python, so..
My doubt is, can I just set this full link as a variable? like

```
mycurl = curl -k "http://myhost.com" -d'{"event": { "Error": "Error Found", "Host": "myhostname"}}'
```

then execute:

```
os.system(mycurl)
```

If it's not possible, or it's incorrect, then how can I use the module requests in this case? Because I want to set an Authorization Token with this curl, which is:

```
curl -k "http://myhost.com" -H "Authorization: MYTOKEN" -d'{"event": { "Error": "Error Found", "Host": "myhostname"}}'
```

Comment: The argument to `os.system()` has to be a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you might do it via `requests`:

```
import requests

# ...

if i in str(read_log):

    url = "http://myhost.com"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": "MYTOKEN"
    }

    payload = {
        "event": {
            "Error": "Error Found",
            "Host": "myhostname"
        }
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    # Do something with response...
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I had some trouble with this payload structure.
One more doubt.. I should fit it like this in my code?

if i in str(read_log):
                response

Answer (score 0):

Like Barmar above said, the argument to `os.system` needs to be a string. You can escape quotes `"` in strings with a backslash `\`. For example:

```
os.system("curl -k \"http://myhost.com\" -d'{\"event\": { \"Error\": \"Error Found\", \"Host\": \"myhostname\"}}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make the `os.system` approach a bit clearer, you can combine f-strings and docstrings:

```
URL = "http://myhost.com"
TOKEN = MYTOKEN
MY_HOSTNAME = myhostname
    
curl_command = f"""curl -k {URL} 
                        -H "Authorization: {TOKEN}" 
                        -d'{"event": { "Error": "Error Found", "Host": {MY_HOSTNAME}}}'
                """
os.system(curl_command)
```